# Vue JS Component reattach or Cache

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource, vuejs2

VueJS component doesn't get cached or atleast reattached after navigation. On refresh or launch everything gets attached and rendered well but after navigating to another page then back. The First Component - Carousel - component in my case doesn't get rendered but the API call is made.

```
<template>
<div class="rel">
    <div id="homeCarousel" class="owl-carousel owl-slider">
        <div class="item" v-for="product in featured">
            <div class="bg-holder top-area-half" >
                <div class="bg-mask-lighten"></div>
                <img class="bg-img" v-bind:src="product.feature_image_url">
                <div class="hero-caption">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3 class="hero-title">{{product.feature_title}}</h3>
                        <p class="hero-subtitle">{{product.feature_subtitle}}</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-white btn-ghost btn-lg hero-btn" href="#">Shop now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hero-slider-nav" class="hero-slider-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<style>

</style>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            featured:[]
        }
    },
    ready(){

    },
    mounted(){
        this.getFeaturedProducts();
    },
    components:{

    },
    methods: {
        getFeaturedProducts: function () {
            Vue.http.get('/api/product/filter/featured=1').then(
                (response) => {
                    this.featured = response.body;
                }
            )
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

`

```
<template>
    <div class="global-wrapper clearfix ">
        <keep-alive>
            <Carousel></Carousel>
        </keep-alive>
 //The rest of the code which is just importing the Component
```

Comment: Did you try without the `keep-alive` option? If it renders once and not rendering again, then it is most likely an issue with `keep-alive`

Comment: I tried without it mad it doesn't render when navigating back

Comment: Then you need to check the values of `this.featured` using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli), to ensure that it has the products array that you expect. If the array length is zero, then you will not see anything on display, though the component might be rendered.

Comment: The first time on visiting the page the network tab shows that as a response, the component got an array of objects as it should. Navigating to another page and back, the request is made a second time and it gets an array of objects. So no "absence of data reason" for it not to render. Plus even if it was not getting data the second time, at least it would show the parent element around the v-for iteration on the dom inspector

Comment: Yes, you should be able to see the parent elements in DOM inspector even if there is no data. This seems to be an issue with router configuration. Your component for Carousel looks fine. Can you recreate this bug in jsFiddle so that we can take a look?

Comment: You can also use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) to store the state of your application (the API data for various components) and reuse it whenever the component re-renders. This allows you to avoid repeated API requests for same data, and you can also skip the `keep-alive` logic entirely. This is something you can do after debugging this issue.

Comment: try [created](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) [lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) instead of mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what i was doing wrong. I had a separate JS/JQuery file and on the document ready i was initializing an owl carousel by id `#('homeCarousel').owlCarousel({})` . What worked was, since i had already bootstrapped owl carousel -> on the mounted lifecycle callback i was now targeting the element and making it an owl carousel.